# jQuery UI Dialog CSS Positioning

Tags: css

I am trying to position an element in the same way as a jQuery-UI dialog.

When a dialog is opened, it sits nicely wherever you have specified its position to be (relative to the viewport).  If however you scroll the page, the dialog moves along with the rest of the page content.

How is this done with CSS?

To clarify - the element I wish to position is hidden and I show it using $("#element").show();

I want it to appear in relation to the viewport and to behave just as a dialog does (will then move as you scroll the page).

Comment: it's either you must catch a page scroll event and move your dialog up and down, or give it a position: fixed; in css.. if that is the effect you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed;` on the dialog box, then use `top` and `left` to position is where you need. This way, it will scroll with the page.

Comment: Position fixed will leave the element fixed in relation to the viewport - it will not scroll with the content.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what effect you're looking for. If you want the box to always be in the same place wherever you scroll, use `fixed`, otherwise use `absolute`.

Comment: If you want it to be in relation to the viewport, it has to be a direct child of the `<body>`... Because `absolute` positions it relative to the parent element.

Comment: Eugene - I want both. To display relative to viewport, then scroll with the content.

Comment: The element is a direct child of <body> - using absolute still does not position in relation to the viewport

Comment: I don't understand how that's not working. Or maybe I'm still not getting what effect you're trying to achieve. Can you show us some code or make a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

A fixed position will cause the dialog to remain in the same place on your browser's screen, even if you scroll. CSS:

```
position: fixed;
```

An absolute position will cause the dialog to stay in the same place in relation to your content, so when you scroll up it will move up with your content. CSS:

```
position: absolute;
```

Here is an example of both: http://jsfiddle.net/sRkbf/

Comment: Absolute positioning does not position in relation to the viewport.

Comment: Absolute positions it in relation to the parent element. Put your dialogue box as a direct child of `<body>` if you want that effect.

Comment: @Billy, I was showing you the difference. Fixed position does position it in relation to the viewport, absolute doesn't, which is what I said in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Reading up on UI dialog, they use the UI position() plugin.  I imagine that they scroll with the page when they are modal.

I have close enough to what I want by using the same.  I have "alerts" for both a dialog and for the page itself.  For the dialog alerts, I used position() to place the alert in the center of the dialog and the center of the viewport for page alerts.  Their position is fixed, but since they are precisely placed its ok.

It would be nice to be able to display an element in relation to the viewport and then have it scroll with the page, like a mix of absolute and fixed, but I have not been able to find anybody who has done it.